# Emphasis needs more space after it

Tags: feature-request, bug, design, formatting

An emphasis gobbles the following space (or does not add some needed additional space),

```
text *text*  text <em>text</em>  text
```

becomes

> text *text*  text *text*  text

(I can't use `\␣` here...) Interestingly, at meta.stackexchange this does not happen. Is it possible to correct this, please?

The "**" is used automatically when the [image] "Emphasis <em> Ctrl+I" button is used.

Comment: what you're asking for, in other words, is an automatic italic correction.  i agree totally.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Yes. When `\textit{}` has it, why should `**` not have it?

Comment: Isn't that more of a bug (or missing feature) in the rendering engines of browsers?

Comment: @Caramdir: Could be. Is there any browser which displays this right (i.e. with italic correction)?

Comment: No layout engine but TeX, AFAIK, has the notion of italic correction, but probably it can be emulated with some CSS voodoo.

Comment: I normally add a `&thinsp;` after the italic text.

Comment: (If I understand you comment about `\␣`:) On that node, `&nbsp;` includes a normal-width but non-breakable space that will not be gobbled (`~`). Anyway, I miss an italic correction, too.